# How to programmatically update SharePoint Feature.xml

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to develop a process by which the feature.xml is updated to include information such as build version, time of activation, and who the feature was activated by. This is extremely useful information in a multi-farm environment.

I have considered a pre-build event in Visual Studio to use a script to update the feature.xml. Another approach would be to use feature receiver. Your Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea do that. Its better to use SharePoint LOG files for this purpose.

Once the feature.xml files are deployed, they are copied to 12 Hive and should be left entirely for SharePoint to manage.

Comment: Madhur, sound response. This is a matter of updating the Feature.xml file as part of the Visual Studio project or updating the Feature definition with in SharePoint on/during/after the feature is deployed.

Funny thing is, I had the code to do this back for MOSS, but I can not source it. As I recall I had the VBscript that was fired on the pre-build event of VS to update the Feature.xml file.